# getting typeError while using dispatch from react context-api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have created a context store using react context API and I a function to dispatch action on  the state but every time I call the function I am getttype errorpeError: dispatch is not a function```

the implementation is of login for the user in react using context API to store the state
my context provider / auth context provider

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch: dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and every time I useContext to get the values of `user,isFetching,error,dispatch`
I am getting undefined for dispatch but the other values are coming correct isFetching is coming false as it should be initially but the value of dispatch is coming undefined.

where I am using the context

```
  const { isFetching, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log({ isFetching, dispatch });
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    e.preventDefault();
    loginCall(
      { email: email.current.value, password: password.current.value },
      dispatch
    );
  };
```

login call function

```
export const loginCall = async (userCredential, dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/auth/login", userCredential);
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a tough one because there aren't any obvious errors.  Can you make an example in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) and link it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import AuthContextProvider in `index.js`
and add this snipet

```
<AuthContextProvider>
   <App/>
</AuthContextProvider>
```